# C# code issue for ASCII to HEX. insight required

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am doing me university project and facing a big issue. i am developing a UI on C# visual studio 2010. I need to open a serial connection and feed some values into the micro controller. basically i have nodes with 24 bits addresses (3 bytes) e.g 0x78A26F.

i take my input from user in the GUI in a text Box. the user shall enter this 78A26F and i want that the serial port sends the following data 0x6F 0xA2 0x78.

But the user input is saved as a string and when i send it through serial connection, the ASCII are sent e.g 0x37 0x38 0x41 0x32 0x36 0x46. i can do the processing in the uC and perform some checks to subtract 0x30 if between 0x30 and 0x39 or subtract 0x37 if between 0x41 and 0x46. but i do not want to use the uC for this calculations. i want to implement some algorithm in the GUI c# for sending the correct HEX value. So i wrote the following program. but i am getting an error. "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte." at code line stating **(data[2 - i] = Convert.ToByte(x*16 + y))**.

I am unable to figure out this issue and fed up now as this should not happen in any case.
if anyone can help me in this regard, either with this code or any other algo/method, i will be really thankful. please, I would prefer never to implement some algo on uC.

Thanks

Maleeha

```
    /***********************************************************************/
    /*The code for opening the serial connection and converting it appropriately*/
    /***********************************************************************/
    byte[] conversion()
    {
        string text = label16.Text.ToUpper(); // if user enters not capital letters
        byte[] data = new byte[3];

        int x, y;
        bool valid;

        for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            valid = true;
            x = (Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(text[2 * i + 1]))); 
            y = (Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(text[2 * i]))); // I want to first send the 0x6F then 0xA2 and finally 0x78. ToChar is so that i can check for A-F

            if(x >= 48 || x <= 57) // i,e it is already a number
                x = Convert.ToInt32(text[2 * i + 1]);
            else if (x >= 65 || x <= 70) // it is between A-F
                x = x - 55; // in case of A, i get 10
            else // any other value i.e greater than F or any other.
            {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }

            if (y >= 48 || y <= 57) // same for y
                y = Convert.ToInt32(text[2 * i]);
            else if (y >= 65 || y <= 70)
            y = y - 55;
            else
            {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }

            if (valid == true)
               data[2 - i] = Convert.ToByte(x*16 + y); // max will be 15*16 + 15 = 255 which should be OK for convert.ToByte.  
        }
        return data;
    }

    void serial(byte[] text)
    {
        SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
        //configuring the serial port
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM1";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;

        //opening the serial port
        serialPort1.Open();

        //write data to serial port
        serialPort1.Write(text, 0, 3);

        //close the port
        serialPort1.Close();
    }
    /***********************************************************************/

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = conversion();
        serial(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET framework already supports converting hex strings.  Make your code look like this:

```
        uint value;
        if (!uint.TryParse(label16.Text,     // Ought to be a text box
               System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out value)) {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid hex value");
            return;
        }
        serialPort1.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0, 3);
```

Comment: hi Hans. thanks for this alot. Very comfortable with this. Just to ensure i got it write... when user enters this, 78A26F, i process though this coe and print the result in conole and also put serially. The Console output is "7905903" which didnt make sense to me. but the hyperterminal out to another pc is "o¢x" which makes sense. as x is for 78, o is for 6F and the middle character is probably for i guess A2. is there any way to check if what A2 corresponds to?

Comment: well i think thats correct too. as the extended ASCII corresponds to the same character i see on hyperterminal for A2. Thanks for this help.

Comment: Convert 0x78a26f to decimal.  Yup, it is 7905903.

Comment: hi hans, it was working fine but something strange happened. the console is still showing the same 7905903. but now the hyperterminal is showing o"x. i.e the middle characater is changed. it corresponds to 22 and not A2. have you ever faced such issues?

Comment: Avoid looking at binary data as though it is a string.  You'll get pretty arbitrary characters for bytes that don't map to an ASCII value.  22 is otherwise A2 with the high bit turned off.

Comment: hmmm... got it. you mean my serial data is perfectally fine? only the hypetterminal is not displaying correctly?

Comment: SO is not a forum.  Click the "Ask Question" button to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to Convert.ToInt32() isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Here's an overview on different usages of Convert.ToInt32():
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx

---

There are three problems with the logic:

1. Look at your if statements that determine if x and y fall within certain number ranges.  Consider what happens if x = 100.  Remember that || means "OR".
2. The conversion if x or y is a character representing a number using Convert.ToInt32() needs to take a string, not a character, in order to get the conversion you're looking for.
3. Once you get past those two, examine your output of your conversion() method. You should notice the final issue.

Comment: hi. But this hasnt corrected it. when i write ,16. there is another whish says invalid arguments.

Comment: @MaleehaTabasam That is because you are probably still converting to a Char as your first argument. Note that the method requires a string, not a char.  The other answers here are pointing you towards far more efficient solutions, but understanding the code you have will be more valuable than simply taking a canned solution. I would suggest you get your solution working first, then explore the other answers here to see how you can simplify this conversion.

Comment: well i got the example from the link you provided which splits hes string and then converts to the string. but i was unable to split my string as there is no delimeter in my string excpet that each pair of character is a delimeter. lolx. any suggestion? anyhow i manage to got it work (i think so) by hans code. but as you said, i would like to develop understanding of my code too whether i wrote the algo correct. Thanks alot.

Comment: @MaleehaTabasam I've updated the answer with some specific hints to help you out with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the [built in methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k.aspx)?

```
byte[] conversion()
{
    string text = label16.Text;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length - 1; i+=2)  //Make sure to increment by 2, currently ignores a trailing char.
    {
        string hex = text.Substring(i * 2, 2);
        data[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex, 16);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Not the cleanest code, but you get the idea.
You should wrap the `data[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex, 16);` line in a try catch, but I am not sure if you want to do that for the line or just call the method in a try catch.

The problem with your code seems to be the lines `x = Convert.ToInt32(text[2 * i + 1]);` and `y = Convert.ToInt32(text[2 * i]);` which are converting the char directly to an int.  to get your solution to work you should do something like `x = ((byte)text[2 * i + 1]) - 48;`